# Exchange Server: Can't login from local network?

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010

i just set up a ms exchange server. login from the server machine itself over OWA works great, but when trying from our local network (direct AND owa), i can't login. can someone please give me a hint where i can configure access control?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Mathias commented, a little bit more description is required. Event logs is a good place to start along with some technical setup.

Assuming you are saying the client access is working through Outlook.

It'd take a look at the Server Config > Client Access.

OWA properties > Authentication tab >> next select the appropriate permission you want, we have 'User name only'

(note these are from Exchange 07, presumably the GUI hasn't changed too much)

Comment: where can i find those event logs?

Comment: Tronic, did you set the Exchange server up by yourself? I fear the basic knowledge is lacking but nevertheless, the event logs found in Event Viewer. Start menu > Administrative Tools > Event Viewer. The Server Config > Client Access is found in the Exchange Management Console.